# Required field only if another field has a value, must be empty otherwise

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

My question is about Laravel [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules).

I have two inputs `a` and `b`. `a` is a select input with three possible values: `x`, `y` and `z`. I want to write this rule:

> `b` **must** have a value **only if** `a` values **is** `x`. 
>   And `b` **must** be empty otherwise.

Is there a way to write such a rule? I tried `required_with`, `required_without` but it seems it can not cover my case.

In other words, if the previous explanation was not clear enough:

- If `a` == `x`, `b` must have a value.
- If `a` != `x`, `b` must be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your own validation rule.

Edit `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and add this validation rule to the `boot` method:

```
// Extends the validator
\Validator::extendImplicit(
    'empty_if',
    function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $data = request()->input($parameters[0]);
        $parameters_values = array_slice($parameters, 1);
        foreach ($parameters_values as $parameter_value) {
            if ($data == $parameter_value && !empty($value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });

// (optional) Display error replacement
\Validator::replacer(
    'empty_if',
    function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(
            [':other', ':value'], 
            [$parameters[0], request()->input($parameters[0])], 
            $message
        );
    });
```

*(optional)* Create a message for error in `resources/lang/en/validation.php`:

```
'empty_if' => 'The :attribute field must be empty when :other is :value.',
```

Then use this rule in a controller (with `require_if` to respect both rules of the original post):

```
$attributes = request()->validate([
    'a' => 'required',
    'b' => 'required_if:a,x|empty_if:a,y,z'
]);
```

It works!

*Side note: I will maybe create a package for this need with `empty_if` and `empty_unless` and post the link here*

Answer (score 3):

[Required if](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if)

> **required_if:anotherfield,value,...**
>   The field under validation must be present and not empty if the anotherfield field is equal to any value.

```
'b' => 'required_if:a,x'
```

Comment: Thanks, but unless I mistake, it covers only the first rule: "If a == x, b must have a value.". But it does not cover the second rule: "If a != x, b must be empty."

Comment: @rap-2-h you need to create a custom rule for this.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin OK, if you want you can post it as an answer. Otherwise, I will post my own. So as you want! :)

Comment: @rap-2-h please post it. )

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8+ check if prohibited and prohibited_if validators work for this:

```
'b' => 'required_if:a,x|prohibited_if:a,!x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has its own method for requiring a field when another field is present. The method is named [`required_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-with).

Comment: the author of the question has mentioned, " I tried required_with, required_without but it seems it can not cover my case." then why are you suggesting the sam thing