# Laravel validation to make sure 2 values are not present at same time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I need to validate a request where if `field1` is present, then `field2` should be empty and vice versa. How can i achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: there are similar answers regarding that, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @KarlHill the value can be empty

Comment: @bhucho i plan to use custom validator, but i would like to know if there is a laravel way of doing this

Comment: Simple jquery on the front for this and pretty easy logic in your controller when posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$rules = array(
    'field1' => 'required_without:field2',
    'field2' => 'required_without:field1',
);
```

Comment: checkout this link you will find your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420718/required-field-only-if-another-field-has-a-value-must-be-empty-otherwise

Answer (score 0):

From [Laravel Docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-prohibits)

> ***#prohibits:anotherfield,...***
> If the field under validation is present, no fields in another field can be present, even if empty.

I think this is what you want:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
   'field1' => 'prohibits:field2',
   'field2' => 'prohibits:field1',
}
```

**What does this means?**

Based on the sample code above we can know once `field1` is present, `field2` is not allowed to be present. Likewise, once `field2` is present, `field1` is not allowed to be present.

Hopefully, this can help you.